# how to make navigation items display the correct active class with php

Tags: php, foreach, navigation

I am building a CMS and I have problems with my navigation. I want to add the class active to the active item in the navigation. This would work fine if I had a page for every item, but I have other sections and links

Here is my code:

```
<div id="main-menu">
<?php foreach ($items as $item) : ?>
    <?php $active = ''; ?>
    <?php if (isset($page)) : ?>
    <?php ($item->pageId === $page->id) ? $active = 'active' : $active = ''; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($item->link == '') : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>front/site/page?x=<?php echo $item->id; ?>" class="<?php echo $active; ?>"><?php echo $item->label; ?></a>
    <?php else : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>" class="<?php echo $active; ?>"><?php echo $item->label; ?></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

When I do not have a page, then I give the link the value provided to point to the specific section. How can I make them all to work fine?

Comment: Holy php tags...heh, not sure I've ever seen someone code PHP that way before.  Anyways, hard to tell what you mean from the context you give.  Perhaps give some example HTML output you are currently getting, and the desired HTML output.  Then example URL's that are supposed to change the behavior.

Comment: Also, when using [ternary comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) try and set the variable in front like `$active = ($item->pageId === $page->id) ? 'active' : '';`

Comment: I loop through all the link items on the menu, I set the active to empty, after that I check if the page id is equal to to link item id, if so then it means my item link is on it's page and I set the $active class. After that I check if I do not have a page set and if not i do some stuff. The output is that for example if I have 5 item links in a menu, with 3 with pages, and 2 without pages, just links to other stuff they will not be active.

Comment: what problem are you facing? your code seems to handle not having a page.

Comment: it doesn't set the class active when not having a page

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that many `<?php ?>` tags! Anyway, your problem seem to be an incorrect usage of the [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary). Try this:

```
<?php 
foreach ($items as $item) :
    $active = ''; 
    if (isset($page)) :
        $active = ($item->pageId === $page->id) ? 'active' : '';
    endif;
    if ($item->link == '') :
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>front/site/page?x=<?php echo $item->id; ?>" class="<?php echo $active; ?>"><?php echo $item->label; ?></a>
    <?php else : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>" class="<?php echo $active; ?>"><?php echo $item->label; ?></a>
    <?php
    endif;
endforeach; 
?>
```

Comment: same thing, that statement was setting $active correctly, the problem is for links without pages

Comment: Your code says that if `$page` is not set, `$active` will be equal to `''`. Are you looking for a different logic?

Comment: yes, for example my news section is a module, my contact is a module and they are linked to, when I am on the news page, or contact page my menu links are not active. Setting the $active if not a page, makes both of them active at the same time.

Comment: Even though his usage of the ternary operator is odd (and not recommended), there's nothing wrong with it. `($item->pageId === $page->id) ? $active = 'active' : $active = '';` will work just fine.

Comment: @KristianAntonsen, yeah, I get this, the var is assigned anyway. But it's odd.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with only *one* pair of PHP tags:

```
<?php

foreach($items as $item)
{
   $active = ($item->pageId == $page->id) ? 'active' : '';
   if(!$item->link)
   {
      echo '<a href="' . ROOT_PATH . '/front/site/page?x=' . $item->id . '" class="' .$active . '">' . $item->label . '</a>';
   }
   else
   {
      echo '<a href="' . $item->link . '" class="' .$active . '">' . $item->label . '</a>';
   }
}

?>
```

Comment: Yea the concatenation operator (.) is your best friend, this is the style I prefer.  Minimizing the php tags makes the code easier to read... well for humans.  The single hyphen notation for strings helps cut down on escaping as well.

Comment: the code was written that way because I was in a template and between php tags there will be more html inserted